# understand new mongo id and use it with iron-router

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

i have a simple post route that looks for the post `_id`.
The problem is that the `pathFor` helper creates a path like this:

```
ObjectID("52e16453431fc2fba4b6d6a8")
```

I guess the mongoDB insertion as been changed and now the `_id` object holds another object inside it called `_str`.

Here is my route:

```
this.route("post", {
        path: "/post/:_id",

        waitOn:function(){
            NProgress.start();
            Meteor.subscribe("Teams");
        },

        before: function () {
            NProgress.done();
        },

        data: function () {
            return Posts.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
        }
    });
```

Currently, it creates an `href` like :

```
 post/ObjectID("52e16453431fc2fba4b6d6a8")
```

clicking on it opens a url

```
post/ObjectID("52e16453431fc2fba4b6d6a8")
```

However, I get the "NotFound" template instead of the post.

How can I fix this?

Comment: ok so mongo insertion now got objectId field inside the _id field, so what i'm trying to figure out is how to make make the pathFor work, i need to get the object inside the _id,usually i would do it with dot notation like that: _id._str 
trying to do path: "/post/:_id._str"      outputs : post/ObjectID("52e16453431fc2fba4b6d6a8")._str

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the `pathFor 'post'` to pass the hex representation of the ObjectId `52e16453431fc2fba4b6d6a8` instead of `ObjectId('52e16453431fc2fba4b6d6a8')`

Try something like this `pathFor 'post' _id=this._id.toHexString`

Once you are passing the hex string, you can use this in your router

`return Posts.findOne({ _id: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(this.params._id)});`

Comment: here _is.toHexString isn't working, so I used: _id=this._id._str

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
this.route("post", {
    path: "/post/:stringId",

    waitOn:function(){
        NProgress.start();
        Meteor.subscribe("Teams");
    },

    before: function () {
        NProgress.done();
    },

    data: function () {
        Post = Posts.findOne({_id: Meteor.ObjectId(this.params.stringId)});
    }
});
```

Now when you go to `post/52e16453431fc2fba4b6d6a8` you should be able to see the correct post.

I am actually planning on using iron-router and objectid's in my application and thinking that this pattern would work.

I have not tried it yet, but let me know if there is a problem and I'll create a small test app to work it out.

Comment: thanks ill check, what's the difference between mongo style objectID and meteor Id anyway?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to [figure out](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/f-ljBdZOwPk). Mongo's objectid kind of embeds a timestamp. Meteor's is random. Meteor seems to have opted for a string only id implementation to make it easier to use id's in routes, id's in dom etc. But I'm not sure about the exact specifics either.