# How to show data from mongoDB with ObjectID

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router, objectid

i have an "back end" application which write in MongoDb (in database i have _id: with ObjectId("13f6ea...002")) i use meteor app to show information. Everything was good i displays list of information with {{#each}}. But when i wanted show one element with '_Id' nothing works.

I read [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317621/understand-new-mongo-id-and-use-it-with-iron-router/23417420#23417420) and adapt my code to get right root, But i can't display anything on the page. I tried to write Template helpers but it didn't helped

Db record:

```
  {
 _id: ObjectId("13f6ea...002"),
 url: "foo",
 title: "bar",
 published: "2014-08-22 03:26:21 UTC",
 image: "foo.jpg",
 summary: "foo ",
 categories: [
   "F",
   "B"
  ],
  ...
  }
```

Route:

```
this.route('news', {
path: '/news/:_id',
template: 'news',
waitOn: function () { 
  var id = this._id; 
  Meteor.subscribe('news', id);
},
data: function() {
  var id = this.params._id;
  return News.findOne({ _id: Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(this.params._id)});
},
 action : function () {this.render();},
});
```

Publish

```
Meteor.publish('news', function(id) {
  return News.find({_id: id}); 
});
```

Template which redirect to unique post

```
<h4><a href="{{pathFor 'news' _id=this._id.toHexString}}">{{title}}</a></h4>
```

And template is just {{news}}

How can i fix this?

---

**UPDATE**

My solutions to fix that:

router.js

```
waitOn: function () {
  var id = this._id;
  Meteor.subscribe('News', id);
},
data: function() {
  return News.findOne(new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(this.params._id));
},
```

and in template

`<a href="news/{{_id._str}}">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to the appropriate url in your browser (i.e. `localhost:3000/news/[_id]`), open the console and enter:

```
Router.current().data()
```

That will show you the data context of the current route.  Either it returns nothing, in which case there is a fundamental problem with your `News.findOne` query as it's returning nothing, or (more likely) it returns the required document.

In the latter case, as far as I can see there is no `news` property within that document, which is why it isn't rendering anything.  If you change `{{news}}` to `{{url}}` or `{{summary}}` I would imagine it would render the requested property.

If by `{{news}}` you're trying to render the entire document, then (aside from the fact that it will render as something like `[Object]`) you need to make `news` a property of the object returned by your data function:

```
return {
    news: News.findOne({ _id: Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(this.params._id)});
};
```

Comment: Thank, for your answer you are right i get 'undefined'. But can't understand what is wrong with my .findOne

Comment: Do you get a result if you just run the same `findOne` query from the console?  If you have a `data` attribute defined in your route controller (if you have one), I think this will override the context set in the route itself, but if your query doesn't return anything when run in the console then that's where your problem is.

Comment: I get `TypeError: this.params is undefined` i have waitOn (not sure if i needed) and data function in my route, as i written above.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the same query as opposed to the same code; `this.params` will be undefined in the console as it's outside the route definition.  You need to run `News.findOne({ _id: Meteor.Collection.ObjectID('[IDSTRING]')})`, with whatever id your supplying in your URL replacing `[IDSTRING]`.

Comment: it doesn't work for my, i tried `Meteor.Collection.ObjectID('[IDSTRING]'._str)})` but doesn't help

Comment: I change my code `return News.findOne({_id: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(this.params._id)});` and route `<a href="news/{{_id._str}}">{{title}}</a>`, template {{title}}, {{url}} if i run 
`Template.news.rendered = function() {
  console.log(this.data);
};` 
I get my object in console, but on page is presented and disappears and if i type in console `Router.current().data()` i get "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Getting Document with _id : 
In the .js file under events, Say on click event and Collection EventList :-

```
    'Submit form' : function () {
        var id = this._id;      
        return EventList.find({_id : id}).fetch();
    }
```

This would return the object for the id. In my Case, I am displaying a field for all documents in Collection. User selects a record and clicks Submit, which fetches all Document fields and displays to the User